# Excel: Finding the sum of a 3rd row by comparing rows that have 2 matching columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I have a workbook where we have monthly phone bills broken down by line and funding codes. There's over 200 lines on this file and growing. I need to find the sum of any rows that have the same cost center and program codes. A cost center may a different program code.

We take the original table and create another table streamlined for one line per unique pairing. This is where we want to have the sum of the original table (with matching criteria) show. There are over 50 cost centers and a dozen programs. So, I'm trying to find a tidy way to do this.

I've been experimenting with index, match, sumifs, and vlookup formulas. I haven't had much luck, but I don't have a lot of experience with them. I also debated whether a macro would work better, but I have even less experience with that.

Here is a sample file. I can't post imbedded pictures yet, so I apologize for the link.

[image: sample sheet image]
[image: current formula (broken)]

Comment: show us your SUMIFS formula using the supplied example.  SUMIFS should be the correct formula to use.

Comment: I've edited my post to include a picture of my current formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the INDEX/MATCH

```
=SUMIFS($U$3:$U$20,$W$3:$W$20,AC3,$X$3:$X$20,AD3)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!